# MySQL: order by next date in schedule

Tags: mysql, schedule

I have 2 tables: one with events, one with schedules for the events:

```
events(id,name,description)

schedules(id,eventid,date,time) // date is a DATE, time is a TIME
```

What would be the most *efficient* way to get all the events, ordered by the *next date* from the schedules, in a single mysql query?

> (for clarification, "next date" means the first date which is > now)

Comment: you want all events once, with the first scheduled date? or all scheduled events ordered by date?

Comment: I want all events (with or without schedules, expired or not) once, ordered by the next date. I do not need to have the next date returned, only ordered by it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LEFT JOIN if you need all events even if there is no NEXT DATE scheduled. If you need events with NEXT DATE then use INNER JOIN

```
select e.id,e.name,e.description, sc.nextDate
from events
left join 
  (
   select s.eventid,
       min(TIMESTAMP(s.date,s.time)) nextDate
   from schedules s
        where TIMESTAMP(s.date,s.time)>NOW() 
   group by s.eventid
  ) sc on e.id=sc.eventid
order by sc.nextDate
```

Comment: it *almost* works: it randomly has events with all_schedules < now() in the return

Comment: the items which have at least one future date are ordered, but between those I see items which have all dates in the past - which I guess is logical, as the WHERE in the subquery will ignore the past dates

Comment: Use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN

Comment: with inner join it will return only the items with future dates, as I need all items to be returned - those with only past dates at the end of the list - see the comments for the question

Comment: I have added order by nextDate asc in the subquery (probably it's redundant) and changed the order by of the main query to sc.nextDate is null,sc.nextDate desc. Seems to be working now, I will do more tests

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
1,e.name,e.description,s.date,s.time
from
events e
inner join schedules s on e.id = s.eventid
where TIMESTAMP(s.date,s.time) > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
union
select 
2,e.name,e.description,s.date,s.time
from
events e
inner join schedules s on e.id = s.eventid
where TIMESTAMP(s.date,s.time) <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
order by 1, TIMESTAMP(s.date,s.time) asc
```

Comment: This will not return the events which have expired schedules

Comment: if you want to order by the next date you cannot show those in the past.. it doesnt make any sense. Can you add an exemple of output please ?

Comment: With union it may work. it selects first the future events order by the date of the event and then the old ones

Comment: if you want also the events without scheduling use a left join in the second union.

Comment: tested, here's what I've noticed: 1. it does return duplicates, if an event has both past and future dates , 2. the order is still not right